# Create grainy/nosy shadows

Tags: texturing, shaders, shadows

How can I accomplish this kind of noisy shadows in Blender?

[image]

Comment: Which Renderer (Internal, Cycles, Eevee, Renderman ...) are you using?

Comment: You could simply use a noise texture for the highlights and a [low sampling rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKIMp.png) for light sources/few bounces.

Comment: @Leander I am using Cycles

Comment: @Leander thnks! going to try it out.

Comment: Hi! @Leander can you please attach the .blend file or an image of your settings for the highlights and the shadows?